# Mongoose schema set timestamp on nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema that looks as follows:

```
{
  "_id": "5073c76a23ce3abf0f000001",
  "asker": {
    "userId": "fooId",
    "firstName": "foo",
    "lastName": "bar",
    "points": "10",
    "aboutMe": "Something about me"
  },
  "isBounty": false,
  "tags": ["mongodb", "nosql", "mongodb-query"],
  "title": "Is there merit to adding flat properties additional to a duplicate nested",
  "descriptionMd": "Question description",
  "offeredPoints": 10,
  "slug": "is-there-merit-to-adding-flat-properties-additional-to-a-duplicate-nested",
  "biddings": [{
    "biddingId": "_biddingId",
    "respondent": {
      "userId": "fooId",
      "firstName": "foo",
      "lastName": "bar",
      "points": "10",
      "aboutMe": "Something about me"
    },
    "biddingPoints": 10,
    "createdAt": "2019-03-21T08:00:00",
    "lastUpdatedAt": "2019-03-21T08:00:00"
  }],
  "acceptedBidding": "_biddingId",
  "answers": [
    {
      "respondent": {
        "address": {
          "userId": "fooId",
          "firstName": "foo",
          "lastName": "bar",
          "points": "10",
          "aboutMe": "Something about me"
        }
      },
      "answerTextMd": "Answer 1",
      "reviewRequested": true,
      "reviewer": {
        "userId": "fooId",
        "firstName": "foo",
        "lastName": "bar",
        "points": "10",
        "aboutMe": "Something about me"
      },
      "reviewStatus": "ANSWER_ACCEPTED",
      "createdAt": "2019-03-21T08:00:00",
      "lastUpdatedAt": "2019-03-21T08:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": "2019-03-21T08:00:00",
  "lastUpdatedAt": "2019-03-21T08:00:00"
}
```

This schema is meant for a Q&A forum and I prefer to keep all data embedded in the question document.

The requirements are as follows:

- Timestamp created and updated are set on the Question document
- Timestamp should be put on the nested biddings and answers as well

I know the default way to put a timestamp on the Question document:

```
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema( {name: String}, {timestamps: true} );
```

How do I put the timestamp dynamically on the nested documents on update?
Is there an advised way of doing, or should I just put the fields there myself and update them manually?

Comment: Can you add all schema code to the question?

Comment: @SuleymanSah What do you mean? This is what the document will look like, I'm still setting up the schema. I'm not sure if I should put createdAt and updatedAt on the schema.

Comment: I mean the other fields in the schema. Now it has only name field.

Comment: @SuleymanSah Ah no, that was merely illustrative. The object above is my full Question object.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can also apply mongoose schema timestamps options to the inner schemas.

For example in the following schema, I applied `timestamps: true` option to the inner biddings schema.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const forumSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    biddings: [
      {
        type: new mongoose.Schema(
          {
            biddingId: String,
            biddingPoints: Number
          },
          { timestamps: true }
        )
      }
    ]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Forum = mongoose.model("Forum", forumSchema);

module.exports = Forum;
```

Now let's test it:

I created a forum document with the following code:

```js
const Forum = require("../models/forum");

router.post("/forums", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Forum.create(req.body);
  res.send(result);
});
```

Request body:

```
{
    "title": "Title 1",
    "biddings": [
        {
            "biddingId": "bidding1",
            "biddingPoints": 10
        },
        {
            "biddingId": "bidding2",
            "biddingPoints": 30
        }
    ]
}
```

Response: (as you see timestamps are both applied to the parent and sub documents)

```
{
    "_id": "5e3073b3a2890b03b029e92c",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "biddings": [
        {
            "_id": "5e3073b3a2890b03b029e92e",
            "biddingId": "bidding1",
            "biddingPoints": 10,
            "createdAt": "2020-01-28T17:47:31.376Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-01-28T17:47:31.376Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e3073b3a2890b03b029e92d",
            "biddingId": "bidding2",
            "biddingPoints": 30,
            "createdAt": "2020-01-28T17:47:31.376Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-01-28T17:47:31.376Z"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2020-01-28T17:47:31.376Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-01-28T17:47:31.376Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Now let's update the bidding point with the `_id:5e3073b3a2890b03b029e92e`

```js
router.put("/forums/:forumId/biddings/:biddingId",
  async (req, res) => {
    let points = req.body.points;

    try {
      let result = await Forum.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.forumId,
        {
          $set: {
            "biddings.$[inner].biddingPoints": points
          }
        },
        {
          arrayFilters: [{ "inner._id": req.params.biddingId }],
          new: true
        }
      );

      if (!result) return res.status(404);

      res.send(result);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
    }
  }
);
```

The url will be like this: `http://.../forums/5e3073b3a2890b03b029e92c/biddings/5e3073b3a2890b03b029e92e`

Request: (it means I want to update the points to 50 of the bidding with `_id:5e3073b3a2890b03b029e92e`:

```
{
    "points": 50
}
```

Response: (as you see `updatedAt` field value of the updated bidding changed automatically from `2020-01-28T17:47:31.376Z` to `2020-01-28T17:50:03.855Z` )

```
{
    "_id": "5e3073b3a2890b03b029e92c",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "biddings": [
        {
            "_id": "5e3073b3a2890b03b029e92e",
            "biddingId": "bidding1",
            "biddingPoints": 50,
            "createdAt": "2020-01-28T17:47:31.376Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-01-28T17:50:03.855Z"   ==> UPDATED
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e3073b3a2890b03b029e92d",
            "biddingId": "bidding2",
            "biddingPoints": 30,
            "createdAt": "2020-01-28T17:47:31.376Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-01-28T17:47:31.376Z"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2020-01-28T17:47:31.376Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-01-28T17:50:03.855Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Can I just say - a detailed response like this that goes the extra mile deserves more upvotes than I can give

Answer (score 0):

whole code is perfect but inside `findByIdandUpdate` query use below code to convert `biddingID` from to `objectid`.

```
arrayFilters: [{ "inner._id": new mongoose.Types.objectId(req.params.biddingId) }]
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was defining the sub schema as a separate entity

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const subSchema =  new mongoose.Schemas({
        biddingId: String,
        biddingPoints: Number
      },
      { timestamps: true })


const forumSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    biddings:[subSchema]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Forum = mongoose.model("Forum", forumSchema);

module.exports = Forum;
```