# Add timestamp to a new subdocument or subschema in mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have this document in mongo atlas

```
_id: 5f8939cbedf74e363c37dd86,
firstname: "Person",
lastname: "Person lastname",
sex: "Masculino",
age: "20",
birthDay: 2020-10-07T00:00:00.000+00:00,
vaccines: Array
 0:Object
  dose: Array
   _id: 5f8939cbedf74e363c37dd87
   vaccine:5f7023ad96f7ed21e85be521
   createdAt:2020-10-16T06:12:27.726+00:00
   updatedAt:2020-10-16T06:12:27.726+00:00
 1:Object
  dose:Array
  _id:5f893a9ca98e97188c93fea8
  vaccine:5f70259796f7ed21e85be523
 2:Object
  dose:Array
  _id:5f893acda98e97188c93fea9
  vaccine:5f7023ad96f7ed21e85be521
```

This is my mongoose schema

```
const mySchema = new Schema({
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  sex: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  age: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  birthDay: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  vaccines: [
    {
      type: new Schema(
        {
          vaccine: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: "Vaccine",
          },
          dose: Array,
        },
        { timestamps: true }
      ),
    },
  ],
});
```

every time I add a new person the vaccines array gets one new object with the timestamp as you can see, in my js file I use this code:

```
const addPerson = (person) => {
  const myPerson= new Model(person);
  return myPerson.save();
};
```

Then when I add a new vaccine for the same person this does not get the timestamp, I'm using this code for that:

```
const addPersonVaccine = async ({ params, body }) => {
  if (!params) return Promise.reject("Invalid ID");
  const vaccines = [body];
  const foundPerson = await Model.updateOne(
    {
      _id: params,
    },
    {
      $push: {
        vaccines: vaccines,
      },
    }
  );
  return foundPerson;
};
```

This is what my body inside vaccines array has:
`[ { vaccine: '5f72c909594ee82d107bf870', dose: 'Primera' } ]`

The problem is that I have no results about the next timestamps, as you can see in my mongo atlas document:

```
1:Object
  dose:Array
  _id:5f893a9ca98e97188c93fea8
  vaccine:5f70259796f7ed21e85be523
 2:Object
  dose:Array
  _id:5f893acda98e97188c93fea9
  vaccine:5f7023ad96f7ed21e85be521
```

Is that the best way to implement timestamps in subdocuments or sub schemas?

I will appreciate your answers, thnks

Answer (score 6):

You can use  mongoose **schema timestamps** options to the **inner schemas**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
    const forumSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        title: { type: String, required: true },
        biddings: [
          {
            type: new mongoose.Schema(
              {
                biddingId: String,
                biddingPoints: Number
              },
              { timestamps: true }
            )
          }
        ]
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    );
    
    const Forum = mongoose.model("Forum", forumSchema);
    
    module.exports = Forum;
```

for more [Mongoose schema set timestamp on nested document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59953941/mongoose-schema-set-timestamp-on-nested-document)

Answer (score 0):

```
const mySchema = new Schema({
firstname: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
lastname: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
sex: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
age: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
birthDay: {
type: Date,
required: true,
},
vaccines: [
{
  type: new Schema(
    {
      vaccine: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "Vaccine",
      },
        dose: Array,
    },
        { timestamps: { createdAt: "created_at", updatedAt: 
        "updated_at" } }
         ),
        },
         ],
       },{ timestamps: { createdAt: "created_at", updatedAt: 
       "updated_at" } }
    );
```

update query

```
testModel
  .updateMany(
    { _id: _id },
    { $push: { vaccines: vaccines } },
    { multi: true }
  )
  .then((update) => {
    res.send(update);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.send(err);
  });
```

Comment: before using this code delete model collection from db after that use these codes and execute them