# mongoose timestamp not showing in sub-document field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need help to resolve this issue, I don't know what I did wrong. I am trying to make the timestamp show on the sub-documents after pushing it to the cart.

I have these two schemas:

```
const productSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    productID: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    color: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    size: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
    }
  },

  { timestamps: true }
);


const cartSchema = new Schema(
  {
    product: {
      type: [productSchema],
    },
  },

  { timestamps: true }
);
```

and this API route:

```
 const createProduct = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    await connectToDB();
    
    const newProduct = await Product.create(req.body);
     const newCart = await Cart.create({});

     Cart.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: newCart._id },
          { $push: { product: newProduct } }
          ,{ new: true }
       ).exec();
    }
    return res.status(201).json({
      message: newProduct,
      success: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.json(error);
  }
};
```

The `newProduct` responses shows the timestamp but it's not showing when pushed to the cart product array. I have tried the traditional method like this:

```
newCart.product.unshift(newProduct);
  newCart.save();
```

I keep getting the updated cart product like this:

```
{
  product: [
    {
      name: 'pegasus',
      productID: '123ghnjmkiii',
      color: 'black',
      size: 'xl',
      _id: new ObjectId("649cb54a3421423e94b8fbb0")
    }
  ],
  _id: new ObjectId("649cb54a3421423e94b8fbaf"),
  createdAt: 2023-06-28T22:33:46.424Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-06-28T22:33:46.424Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

This is what I want:

```
{
      product: [
        {
          name: 'pegasus',
          productID: '123ghnjmkiii',
          color: 'black',
          size: 'xl',
          _id: new ObjectId("649cb54a3421423e94b8fbb0")
          createdAt: 2023-06-28T22:33:46.424Z,
          updatedAt: 2023-06-28T22:33:46.424Z,
        }
      ],
      _id: new ObjectId("649cb54a3421423e94b8fbaf"),
      createdAt: 2023-06-28T22:33:46.424Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-06-28T22:33:46.424Z,
      __v: 0
    }
```

Comment: Did you try after reading mongoose official docs?  You have to try "Timestamps on Subdocuments" section.[<<refer this>>](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/timestamps.html#:~:text=Mongoose%20also%20supports%20setting%20timestamps,not%20the%20top%20level%20document). I recommend you to try simple queries instead of try aggregations first.

Comment: Thank you, i was able to resolve it I got my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75651635/12194198